# Asterisk: chan_sip.c:4321 __sip_reliable_xmit: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data

Tags: raspberry-pi, asterisk, pbx

I have a setup of Asterisk PBX running on a Raspberry Pi 1 (IP 192.168.2.2) and it runs a few local IP phones just fine. I recently purchased a Grandstream HT813 gateway (IP 192.168.2.3) to connect both an analog phone to IP and IP to the PSTN.

The analog phone works perfectly and dialing in *from* the PSTN works perfectly. Dialing out was much more problematic. First of all, I have the following in my sip.conf: (I didn't include the other phones, just the FXO port)

```
[general]
context=default
sipdebug=yes
bindaddr=0.0.0.0

[FXO]
type=peer
context=inbound
host=192.168.2.3
insecure=port
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
secret=secret_was_here
```

I redacted the secret above for obvious reasons. When I dail out to the PSTN via a IP phone (IP 192.168.2.5), I get the following error, where `[myphonenumber]` is my cell phone number that I was calling to test:

```
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.2'
    -- Executing [[myphonenumber]@local:1] Goto("PJSIP/104-00000000", "dialout,[myphonenumber],1") in new stack
    -- Goto (dialout,[myphonenumber],1)
    -- Executing [[myphonenumber]@dialout:1] Dial("PJSIP/104-00000000", "SIP/FXO/[myphonenumber], 30") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
Audio is at 13370
Adding codec ulaw to SDP
Adding codec alaw to SDP
Adding codec gsm to SDP
Adding non-codec 0x1 (telephone-event) to SDP
Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.2.3:5060:
INVITE sip:[myphonenumber]@192.168.2.3 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.2:5060;branch=z9hG4bK71b94203
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:104@192.168.2.2>;tag=as162b0b68
To: <sip:[myphonenumber]@192.168.2.3>
Contact: <sip:104@192.168.2.2:5060>
Call-ID: 3dc727711219fa6e4171966d519ac8ee@192.168.2.2:5060
CSeq: 102 INVITE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 16.2.1~dfsg-1
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 19:11:17 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 291

v=0
o=root 1202030057 1202030057 IN IP4 192.168.2.2
s=Asterisk PBX 16.2.1~dfsg-1
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.2
t=0 0
m=audio 13370 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv

---
[Aug 15 20:11:17] ERROR[23679][C-00000001]: chan_sip.c:4321 __sip_reliable_xmit: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data
```

So I set up a switch port to mirror the output of my Asterisk server Pi. It sends no data to the gateway when this error occurs, so the problem is in Asterisk. I have seen many posts saying that this is a permission or firewall error, of course. First of all, I disabled the firewall on the Asterisk server during testing. (It's a small network) I also ran `nmap -v -sU -p 5060 192.168.2.3`, which confirmed that my gateway is working just fine. If I run that command as the Asterisk user, I get a permission error, of course. I see nothing else in the syslog. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I had another look at it and I traced the call through the C code. It looks like the issue is that the `sipsock` variable (line 1101) is set to -1 when `sip_prepare_socket` confirms that the connection requires a UDP socket (line 29503). This returns -1 throwing an error into `__sip_xmit`. I will search my log files for any additional information. Also, my Asterisk version is v16.2.1.